# Not able to read the JQuery data sent from Ajax in Java Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jquery

Here is my Ajax code:

```
var email="abc@abc.com";    

    $.ajax({
        url : "ships",
        data : "{email" + email.toString() + "}",
        success : function(data){
            alert(data)
        },
        error : function(data) {
            console.log("error:", data);
        },

        type : "post"
    });
```

And here is my Java Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(request.getParameter("email"));


}
```

I CANNOT read data in Java Servlet The console prints out the following value for email:

null

I am using Tomcat 7

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong and why i cannot read data in Java Servlet_

Comment: what firebug says? have you check

Comment: It says that parameter is sent to the  servlet ,but in java servlet when i tries to do get parameter i am receiving the null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `data` of the param object is a JavaScript object, so to send a parameter named `EmailAddress` you would do:

```
...
url : "ships",
data : {
    EmailAddress: email.toString()
},
success : function(data){
    ...
```